# CentOS or Ubuntu server for pacemaker (heartbeat) cluster?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, cluster, pacemaker

Could someone share their knowledge and experience with CentOS and Ubuntu server management, maintenance capabilities and community support? I would be running pacemaker cluster and LAMP stack on it with GFS2 (or OCFS2) and other services.

Currently I have Gentoo system and I am almost happy with it but now I consider moving my applications to cluster system and I think that Gentoo is sometimes "not reliable" for maintenance.

So... Which should be easier to manage and more reliable distribution in my case?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, Ubuntu would be easier to manage. The community is pretty strong, Canonical Inc put enormous efforts to fix bugs and provide support. They are also ahead in their software versions - most of Ubuntu packages are newer than the ones in RHEL/CentOS. 
However, GFS/GFS2 comes from Red Hat, so presumably CentOS should be better with it. Red Hat backports new features in its kernel (TRIM for instance). CentOS 6 came with very long delay, compared to the previous CentOS releases. Also, RHEL is up to 6.1 since May 2011, no signs from CentOS about it.

Personally, I switched from CentOS 5.5 to Ubuntu 8.04/9.10/10.04. I am happy with it.

Just my $0.02.